# How to find music at 60/90/180 bpm to sync with exercise?

Tags: running, bicycling, jogging, intensity

I follow the recommendation that it's good practice to run with a close to 170/180 bpm pace, at any speed (slow or fast). That is, when running you should be hitting the floor around 180 times per minute, which is near to 3 per second, in a somewhat waltz rythm. I understand this bpm timing is also recommendable for riding a bicycle. 
One available resource to get to this pace is a **metronome**, that is many times included in the features of different watches, such as the **gps** type.

The broader question is if it's possible to find musics that have this type of rythm. There's [a page that does this for you: jog.fm](https://cycle.jog.fm/). It's awesome but it just offers song by song ideas. 
I'd like to know:

### Is there a software that grabs a music collection at 180 bpm?

...perhaps possible to fetch from my hard drive directly, or online music. Most likely a fitness instructor, or even *a dj should be able to answer* this. Open source options? Maybe there's even a certain amount of **music genre** that can answer this directly, say a set of **LPs** that have this pace.

#### Is there at least one LP that has a 180 rpm?

I think perhaps something by Kraftwerk, but just guessing.

Comment: Nilon, though I like your question, honestly I don't feel music is always related to performance. Though it may seem like it's giving you a mental edge, there are self-driven individuals who do it without any external boost like music or any other kinda beat. If you are already following the guideline of 3 hits per second(which may not work for others) all you need to do is find it with someone with the knowledge of music. I'm not sure any fitness guy could help here. There are  a few software to customize music and create your own remix. I don't know where they are, but I know they exist.

Comment: @xCodeZone actually I don't exercise with music, but I think it could be useful for those who do, or even to listen before exercise to get in rythm.

Comment: Not really sure this is exercise related. The only exercise connection is "I think it's a good idea to run at 180 bpm", the main question is "help me find software/music". It might be a fit at software recommendations, but not sure it's on topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about finding software/music.

Comment: @JohnP the question is intended to be connected to another question posted here that wasn't closed: [What are the ways to reach the optimal running cadence (180 steps per minute)?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6649/what-are-the-ways-to-reach-the-optimal-running-cadence-180-steps-per-minute/6831#6831). It's just narrowing it down.

Comment: This question has been reposted [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36823/how-to-find-music-at-60-90-180-bpm-to-sync-with-exercise)

Answer (score 3):

I love to run based on BPM. I find that my feet tend to sync with whatever I am listening to anyhow.

## Spotify

I am currently playing around with Spotify. They have a feature (under Browse... Running) in the mobile app to use a running playlist and when you fire it up it asks you to start running and they will detect your cadence or you can skip that and manually set it. I like it but it burns through my mobile data too much because you can't cache those playlists.

I have also worked a bit using [SmarterPlaylists](http://smarterplaylists.playlistmachinery.com/index.html) to create playlists by BPM. This helps because I can download those playlists for offline use.

## Other

Here are some other solutions that I have used:

- download techno music from http://podrunner.com,
- search for songs by bpm at:

  - http://bpmdatabase.com,
  - http://jogtunes.com,
  - http://runningmusicmix.com,
  - or http://runningplaylist.net.

Good luck to you and happy running!